# Combining several images in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have these several images which I need to be combined using BufferedImage in java. The logic of the program is this:
The user will be asked to input data (5 times) then the inputted value will be generated to image (I'm done coding with this part). My problem is how can I Combine them into one image only. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to tile 5 images next to each other into one image? Make your Q. more clear!

Comment: what do you mean by combnining? tile? overlap? or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another new image. Depending on how you would like to combine the images you have two possibilities:

1. Call `getGraphics()` on the newly create `BufferedImage` and use `drawImage()` multiple times to draw your other images into the newly created one (for example to create a tiled image with all the images you create beforehand)
2. Call `getRaster()` on the newly create `BufferedImage` and use the methods of this object to draw information from your other images into this image (this way you can achieve any blend effects you might need)